# Url regex oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I want to do something like this :

This is the link I want to replace. So I want only to keep the "textIwantToKeep" part :
http://mylink/aaa-bbb/textIwantToKeep

And I want this : 
http://mySecondLink/ccc-ddd/textIwantToKeep

I want to use regular expression with Oracle SQL Developper. I think about to count the number of slash (4) and to split only the part before the 4th slash but it doesn't work..

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXP_SUBSTR` might be one option; `\w+$` returns the last *word* (i.e. the one "anchored" to the end of the string):

```
SQL> with test (link) as
  2    (select 'http://mylink/aaa-bbb/textIwantToKeep'       from dual union all
  3     select 'http://mySecondLink/ccc-ddd/textIwantToKeep' from dual
  4    )
  5  select link,
  6         regexp_substr(link, '\w+$') result
  7  from test;

LINK                                        RESULT
------------------------------------------- --------------------
http://mylink/aaa-bbb/textIwantToKeep       textIwantToKeep
http://mySecondLink/ccc-ddd/textIwantToKeep textIwantToKeep

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be other alternatives, but here is something that came to me quickly -

```
WITH main_table AS (
    SELECT 'http://mylink/aaa-bbb/textIwantToKeep' AS original_string FROM dual
    )
    , 
    second_table AS (
    SELECT 'http://mySecondLink/ccc-ddd/' AS my_second_link FROM dual
    )
SELECT
    second_table.my_second_link
    || regexp_substr(main_table.original_string, '[^/]+', 1, 4) AS final_string
FROM
    main_table,
    second_table;
```

Let me know if that works.